# Why I'm unable to set error to formik field using setFieldError or setError?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, validation, formik

I'm using formik in my React Native App like this:
In constructor `this.myRef = React.createRef();`

Creating my form component is like this

```
<AppForm
    innerRef={this.myRef}
    initialValues={{ currentPassword: '', newPassword: '', confirmPassword: '' }}
    validationSchema={validationSchema}
    onSubmit={() => ''}
    >

    <AppFormField
        heading='Current Password'
        name='currentPassword'
        autoCapitalize='none'
        secureTextEntry={!showCurrentPassword}
        icon={showCurrentPassword ? 'eye' : 'eye-off'}
        onIconClick={() => this.setState({ showCurrentPassword: !showCurrentPassword })}
    />
    
</AppForm>
```

Where AppForm is my custom formik form component and AppFormField is a custom component.

(I'm using ref bcz I'm submitting the form using Save button outside the form component)

Calling handle submit like this `onBtnPress={() => this.handleSubmit()}`

And finally the handleSubmit function where I want to set the error.

```
handleSubmit = async () => {

    this.myRef.current?.submitForm();
    this.myRef.current.setErrors({currentPassword: 'Hello'});
    this.myRef.current.setFieldError('currentPassword', 'Hello'); // I've tried both ways
    console.log('CurrentRef ', this.myRef.current);
}
```

I've tried both setErrors and setFieldError and expecting the formik to set the error "Hello" to the field 'currentPassword' but I'm unable to do so. Please tell me the mistake if any and tell me the correct way.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the problem was with the way I was calling the method. `setFieldError` and `setErrors` both are **async** and I was calling them without the **await**.

Comment: Are you sure? Both of them are Synchronous.

Comment: @Behzad adding "await" worked so, that's indicating something is asynchronous in it.

Comment: Despite my linter yelling at me for this anti-pattern, adding await solved this for me too. This still feels more like a workaround than how it should work

Answer (score 0):

A.You need to add `errors` in your Formik component

B. you use `setFieldError` caller `setFieldError("currentPassword", "Hello")`([info](https://github.com/jaredpalmer/formik/releases/tag/v0.8.0))

Comment: For A: I'm getting other validation errors in handleSubmit function "errors" correctly in "this.myRef.current".
For B: Sorry, it was a typing mistake during writing the question. I've now corrected it. I'm already using caller `setFieldError('currentPassword', 'Hello')`